# Filter for my Custom Logs in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

i am new to the ELK stack, I want to use ELK stack to push my logs to elastic so that I can use Kibana on em. Below is the format of my custom log:

```
Date Time INFO - searchinfo#username#searchQuery#latitude#longitude#client_ip#responseTime
```

The below is an example of a log that follows the format.

```
2017-07-04 11:16:10 INFO  - searchinfo#null#gate#0.0#0.0#180.179.209.54#598
```

Now I am using `filebeat` to push my `.log` files to `logstash` and logstash would push that data into elastic.

I need help, writing up a `filter` for config for `logstash` that would simply split using the `#` and then put data into respective fields into elastic index.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [grok plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) to parse your logs into structured data:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\A%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:var0}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE}%{SPACE}(?<searchinfo>[^#]*)#(?<username>[^#]*)#(?<searchQuery>[^#]*)#(?<latitude>[^#]*)#(?<longitude>[^#]*)#(?<client_ip>[^#]*)#(?<responseTime>[^#]*)" }
  }
}
```

You can debug it [online](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/):

[image]

Comment: There is this issue with the filter, the response time is not a number type, rather it's a array of text type. How do I put it to number type?

Comment: @AdityaSharma Use [date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `grok filter` to parse your log.

You can try with this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\A%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:var0}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE}%{SPACE}(?<var1>[^#]*)#(?<var2>[^#]*)#(?<var3>[^#]*)#(?<var4>[^#]*)#(?<var5>[^#]*)#(?<var6>[^#]*)#(?<var7>[^#]*)" }
  }
}
```

This will parse you log and add fields named var0, var1, etc to the parsed document. You can rename this variables as you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please share how can I edit the variable names? Or is it just via that query I can replace var0 and all

Comment: you can just change var0 and the other with whatever name you want

Comment: There is this issue with the filter, the response time is not a number type, rather it's a array of text type. How do I put it to number type?

Comment: array of text?? show an example of a parsed document as it appears on kibana

Comment: I've put up a different question for it. I've switched to apache logs since this seemed to be tedious. [the referance link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978156/logstash-custom-log-filter-for-apache-logs)

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AsbwVCO9nR4ogvIgNNFpKM1VQIcdXg is the image. Have a look everything is of type string