# logstash Custom Log Filter for Apache Logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

i am new to the ELK stack. I have a filebeat service sending logs to logstash, and in logstash using a `grok` filter, the data is pushed to an `elasticsearch` index.

I am using the `gork` filter with `match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}` to parse the data.

My Issue is, I want the names of the fields and their values to be stored in the elasticsearch index. My different versions of the logs are as below:

---

```
27.60.18.21 - - [27/Aug/2017:10:28:49 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=pradeep.pgu&location=28.5359586,77.3677936&query=atm&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3284
27.60.18.21 - - [27/Aug/2017:10:28:49 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=pradeep.pgu&location=28.5359586,77.3677936&query=atms&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 1452
27.60.18.21 - - [27/Aug/2017:10:28:52 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/nearby/json?&refLocation=28.5359586,77.3677936&keyword=FINATM HTTP/1.1" 200 3283
27.60.18.21 - - [27/Aug/2017:10:29:06 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=pradeep.pgu&location=28.5359586,77.3677936&query=co&explain=true&bridge=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3415
27.60.18.21 - - [27/Aug/2017:10:29:06 +0530] "GET /api/v1.2/places/search/json?username=pradeep.pgu&location=28.5359586,77.3677936&query=cof&explain=true&bridge HTTP/1.1" 200 2476
```

---

The fields that I want in the elastic index are below:

1. client_ip  => type must be compatible to what kibana uses for IP mapping.
2. timestamp  => datetime format. => the time the of the log
3. method     => text => the method that was called e.g. GET,POST
4. version    => decimal number => e.g. 1.2 / 1.0 (in the sample logs as v1.2)
5. username   => text => it's the text after the `username=` (in the sample log as pradeep.pgu)
6. location   =>geo_point type => the value has both latitude and longitude so that kibana can plot these on the map.
7. search_query => text => the thing that was searched (in the sample from either of the two fields "keyword=" or "query="). Either of the two fields would be present and the one that is present, it's value must be used.
8. response_code => number => the code of the response. (in the sample as 200)
9. data_transfered => number => the amount of data transferred (the last number in the sample).

Is such a thing even possible? Does the gork filter has a provision for this? The thing is the parameters are not order specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from the `HTTPD_COMMONLOG`, you could use this pattern (which you can test at [grok tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result)):

```
grok {
 match => { 
  "message" => "%{IPORHOST:client_ip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{HTTPDUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:method} /api/v%{NUMBER:version}/places/search/json\?%{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response_code} (?:%{NUMBER:data_transfered}|-)"
 } 
}
```

Once the grok filter have extracted the request, you can use the kv filter on it, which will extract the parameters (and ignore the problem of the parameters not being order specific). You'll have to put the `field_split` option to &:

```
kv { 
  source => "request"
  field_split => "&"
}
```

For `search_query`, depending on which field is present, we use the `mutate` filter with the `add_field` option to create the field.

---

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { 
            "message" => "%{IPORHOST:client_ip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{HTTPDUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:method} /api/v%{NUMBER:version}/.*/json\?%{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response_code} (?:%{NUMBER:data_transfered}|-)"
        } 
    }
    kv { 
        source => "request"
        field_split => "&"
    }

    if [query] {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "search_query" => "%{query}" }
        }
    } else if [keyword] {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "search_query" => "%{keyword}" }
        }
    }

    if [refLocation] {
        mutate {
            rename => { "refLocation" => "location" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your pattern in grok debugger, it said compiler error. [link to debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I've replaced the pattern with the full grok configuration. Apparently the debuger you link does not support the some parts of the pattern I've used. With the one I've linked it work without problem.

Comment: I've tested the pattern in my answer with logstash 5.5.0 and it works.

Comment: thanks for that, I really appreciate it. Would you be able to share a sample of the  entire filter field as well? with the kv filter and the field. I am getting a little confused with the kv filter

Comment: especially the part where if query parameter is present then search_string field in elastic has the data of the query parameter and if the keyword parameter is present then the search_string has the keyword parameters value.

Comment: See my edit for my entire filter configuration. And I don't understand anything from your last comment.

Comment: What I meant was, if you see the sample logs I've shared, there are two either or fields, 1. query or keyword and 2. location or refLocation. Now I have a field in elastic called search_query (of type text) so incase I get a query parameter in the request I want to set the value passed in the query parameter into the search_query field else if the keyword was passed in the request then I want to set the value passed in the keyword parameter to the search_query. How can I do this if and else

Comment: Also, I have a field in elastic called location (of type geo_point), now i want that the value of the latitude and longitude to be passed into this field so that the location field can get a value of type geo_point. For example the way to define a geo_point is [latitude, longitude]

Comment: Got it. I'll try to add the missing parts.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and time. I really appreciate it. Looking forward to your updated answer

Comment: I've added the part for the `search_query`. For `location`, the format "lat,lon" should work (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query.html#_lat_lon_as_string_2)), so I've just renamed `refLocation` in `location`.

Comment: Hi It works amazingly well. Cheers. There is only one issue, all the data is of string type. the response code, the response  times, the data transferred. everything. How do I get them to be numbers?

Comment: I did thought about that. For the conversion, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38047850/6113627

Comment: So I should do that for all my fields? that's kinda a long process. What about the client_address and location? what data type should it be to be able to use on kibana.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do that for all the fields you want to convert. For the ip adress and the location, I don't know, it should be a configuration on the elasticsearch side, with the mapping used by the index where you put your data (and no, I have no idea how to do it, you'll have to ask another question).